# How do I find the magnitude of a complicated complex number?

Tags: impedance, math

How do I find the magnitude of something like $$1+(Z_c+R) \times Z_l$$?

(\$Z_l\$ is the impedance of an inductor.)

Comment: I'm not quite following the question - are you looking for a generalized formula that gives you the magnitude in terms of Zc, R, and ZI, or are you concerned that simply evaluating and taking the magnitude of the final complex number won't do what you want?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a math question.

Comment: replace Z with R+jX and solve for Z'

Comment: @nanofarad I know how to find the mangitude of a complex number when its in the for x+jy but I'm not sure how to handle things when its x+jy+jz. Do I just factor out the j and so its in the from x+jy and solve?

Comment: use Pythagoras Theorem

Comment: @kefffin x + jy + jz is nothing more than x + j(y+z). There's nothing "magical" about the simplification; you just simplify your complex-valued *expression* to a single complex number and find the magnitude, much like finding the absolute value of (3+4-15) would have you first simplify to a single number and then find the absolute value.

Comment: BTW in your example units does not match. Writing 1+(Zc+R)*Zl you're trying to sum 1 (unitless) to squared ohms

Comment: Can you show the circuit? Because something is not right. As for the magnitude \$Z = \sqrt{(1 + \frac{L}{C})^2 + (\omega L R)^2}\$

Answer (score 1):

Using \$Z_C=\frac{1}{j\omega C} \$ and \$Z_L=j\omega L \$ you get
$$1+Z_L(Z_C+R) = 1+j\omega L \bigg(\frac{1}{j\omega C}+R \bigg) $$
Multiply out the paranthesis, get the complex number on rectangular form (z = a+jb) and use Pythagoras Theorem to compute the magnitude of the number.

Comment: Yeah I'm still confused from there out. When I go to use pythag theorem do I just "drop" the j? sqrt[ 1+(L/C)^2 + (RwL)^2] ?

Comment: j^2 = -1 . . . . .

Comment: @kefffin The magnitude/absolute value/modulus of a complex number z = a +jb is obtained as \$|z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \$. But this is just a pure maths definition, and you should be able to look this up.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at this from a purely math based approach, we can define $$Z = 1 + (Z_C+R) Z_L$$

Then the magnitude of \$Z\$ can be defined as $$ |Z| = \sqrt{Z \bar Z}$$

Where \$\bar Z \$ is the complex conjugate of \$Z\$

Then we can map \$Z_C = \frac{1}{j\omega C}\$ and \$Z_L = j\omega L\$

$$ Z = 1 + (\frac{1}{j\omega C} + R) j\omega L $$

$$ Z = 1 + \frac{L}{C} + j\omega RL $$

$$ \bar Z = 1 + \frac{L}{C} - j\omega RL $$

$$ Z \bar Z = \frac{L^2}{C^2} + 2\frac{L}{C} + 1 + \omega^2 R^2 L^2 $$

$$ |Z| = \frac{1}{C}\sqrt{L^2 + 2LC + C^2 + \omega^2 R^2 L^2 C^2} $$